# Remove ?m= string from urls

Tags: .htaccess

I have urls like

```
site.com/gallery/var/resizes/somename/somename1/somename2.jpg?m=somenumber
```

would like to remove the ?m=somenumber part from urls and simply show

```
site.com/gallery/var/resizes/somename/somename1/somename2.jpg
```

how to achieve this through htaccess

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What have you tried?

Comment: In my htaccess i have this to redirect all my old urls to home page

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=301]


But the above urls like 

site.com/gallery/var/resizes/somename/somename1/somename2.jpg?m=somenumber

adds /?m=somenumber at the end

so would like to remove it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two parts:

1. Rewrite rules in your .htaccess so that it recognizes the changed rules
2. URL generation in your web application, so that it generates URLs the way you want.
3. is definitely the harder part here.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R=301,L]
```

As a result it gives me :

```
site.com/gallery/var/resizes/somename/somename1/somename2.jpg
```

Comment: It gives me

site.com/var/resizes/somename/somename1/somename2.jpg

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce, works for me...